# How to center a page on the screen using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

i use this code:

```
jQuery("#page").css({"left":+'"'+(jQuery(window).innerWidth()-1083)/2+'px"'});
```

I don't get any errors, but the page isn't centered.

I tried various versions, nothing helped. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Answer (score 1):

What is that `+` sign doing there? Try this:

```
$("#page").css("left", ($(window).innerWidth() - 1083) / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the value in additional quotes, replace with:

```
jQuery("#page").css({"left": (jQuery(window).innerWidth()-1083)/2+'px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it with jQuery. Do it with CSS:

```
 #page{
    left:50%;
    margin-left: 541.5px;
 }
```

(1083/2)=541.5

Answer (score 0):

you have positioned the `#page` absolutely which is not necessary for the wrapper, you can position it relatively and use auto margin .

```
#page {
   position: relative:
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```